# Filter JSON Object by comparing nested object inside it and other array using javascript or jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object, filter

Lets say i have `var myVar = ['google','search','engine','results','count']`

for Eg:JSON Object `

```
myJSON = [{
     'title' : 'Google',
     'url' : 'www.google.com',
     'tags' : ['google','search','engine']
},{
     'title' : 'Yahoo',
     'url' : 'www.yahoo.com',
     'tags' : ['Yahoo','search','engine','news']
},{
     'title' : 'MSN',
     'url' : 'www.msn.com',
     'tags' : ['msn','search','engine','news']
},{
     'title' : 'Facebook',
     'url' : 'www.facebook.com',
     'tags' : ['social','search','media','chat','friends']
},]
```

I want to filter `myJSON` by comparing two arrays `myVar` and `tags` in `myJSON`.

suppose `myVar = ['search']`
filter should return all objects in `myJSON`
if `myVar = ['engine']`
filter should return only 3 objects of `myJSON` in which `myVar` array matched with `tags` array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var myVar = ['engine'];
myJSON = [{
  'title': 'Google',
  'url': 'www.google.com',
  'tags': ['google', 'search', 'engine']
}, {
  'title': 'Yahoo',
  'url': 'www.yahoo.com',
  'tags': ['Yahoo', 'search', 'engine', 'news']
}, {
  'title': 'MSN',
  'url': 'www.msn.com',
  'tags': ['msn', 'search', 'engine', 'news']
}, {
  'title': 'Facebook',
  'url': 'www.facebook.com',
  'tags': ['social', 'search', 'media', 'chat', 'friends']
}];

for (var i = 0; i < myVar.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < myJSON.length; j++) {
    if (JSON.stringify(myJSON[j]['tags']).indexOf(myVar[i]) >= 0) {
      console.log(myJSON[j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use functional approach that is fast, concise and easy to understand:

```
var myVar = ['engine']

var myJSON = [{             'title' : 'Google',
                              'url' : 'www.google.com',
                              'tags' : ['google','search','engine']
                            },{
                              'title' : 'Yahoo',
                              'url' : 'www.yahoo.com',
                              'tags' : ['Yahoo','search','engine','news']
                            },{
                              'title' : 'MSN',
                              'url' : 'www.msn.com',
                              'tags' : ['msn','search','engine','news']
                            },{
                              'title' : 'Facebook',
                              'url' : 'www.facebook.com',
                              'tags' : ['social','search','media','chat','friends']
                            }]

var filtered = myJSON.filter(function(i){ 
   return myVar.reduce(function(result, current) { 
       return result || i.tags.some(function(v){ return v==current })  }, false)
   }) ;

console.log("Filtered", filtered);
```

See [reduce](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp) and [filter](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) array function references for more details.

You should not stringify objects and use string operations over them, that would introduce an additional non-needed overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` and `some` functions of array like below.

```
var result = myJSON.filter(function(item){
  return item.tags.some(function(str){
        return myVar.indexOf(str) > -1;
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L45n41ev/)